# Dynamically add and remove UITableViewCells to UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I'm building an app where a user is able to provide different usernames that he/she has. The vision is, the user is able to add and remove UITableViewCell to enter a username.

Right now I have a grouped UITableView and on the right hand side of every UITableViewCell I have a UIButton that adds another cell to the table with a UITextField. After the first cell, every cell has a delete button. I'm trying to make the UIButton delete that row. I have the IBAction that removes the cell, the only problem is, it's not deleting the proper row.

What is the best way to do what I'm attempting to do? I don't know how to properly search for this on Google. I'm sure someone has done what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to what Derek said above -- `UITableViewController` already provides functionality to delete rows.

To toggle editing a `UITableView`, do something like: `[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];`

Override `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` with something like (since it sounds like you don't want your first row to be deletable):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Also override `tableView:commitEditingStyle:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1];

        // delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to code what a table view already has. Look into the built in editing facilities of a table view and you will find thaaat you don't need to have these unbuttons as table views and delegates have editwing facilities built in.

Your comment about deleting the wrong thing makes me think you have an issue with matching row numbers to indexes of your source data.